# Add period to section numbering AND change font style of subsections simultaneously

Tags: sectioning

A journal is requiring me to have the following formatting:

**1. Section**

1.1. *Subsection*

Note that for the subsection the numbering is also unbolded.

In other words, add a period to all sections, but remove the bold from subsections and add italics to just the title.

Using this site I've figured out how to do either of the two above but not both. People who want to add the period use this

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

But then when someone wants to italicize, they suggest

\titleformat{\subsection}

```
   {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{12}{17}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

How can one of the two be adjusted to accomplish both tasks? This is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: if a journal is that fussy, then they really should provide their own document class.  this isn't something authors should be expected to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{tgheros}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesection.}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\sffamily}
  {\thesubsection.}
  {1em}
  {\itshape}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MikeCorbin The secret is “been there, done that”. `;-)`